# Entity Framework 4.1 Retrieving self referencing data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework 4.1 code first and ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am struggling to get my self referencing setup properly.  I have a Category class.  It must be self referencing to itself.  A category can be a parent category when the ParentCategoryId in the table is null.  If a category has a ParentCategoryId with a value then it means that it belongs to a parent category.

I followed this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code) on Code Project.

Here is my Category class:

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
     public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
     public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My context class:

```
public class PbeContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
     {
          dbModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

          dbModelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
               .HasOptional(c => c.ParentCategory)
               .WithMany()
               .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentCategoryId);
     }
}
```

Not sure if the above is correct?

Can someone please help me get this right?  What I need is that when I query a category by id then it must bring back the parent category (only loaded when needed).  Also it must load any child categories (only when needed).  I have not yet added a list to the category class for the child categories.

What would the above quesries look like to retrieve a category with it parent category and child categories?

**EDIT**

This is how I retrieve my category:

```
public Category GetById(int id)
{
     return db
          .Categories
          .Find(id);
}
```

Because the ParentCategory reference can be null, how would I display this in the view?  I have the following:

```
@Model.ParentCategory.Name
```

..but won't it give an error if the category has no parent category associated with it?  How would I display it in the view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to access child categories you can add a collection property to your model

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
     public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
     public bool IsActive { get; set; }
     public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
     public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can setup the model as

```
      dbModelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
           .HasOptional(c => c.ParentCategory)
           .WithMany(c => ChildCategories)
           .HasForeignKey(p => p.ParentCategoryId);
```

**Edit**

You should check whether `ParentCategory` is null or not.

```
@if(Model.ParentCategory != null){
  <div>@Model.ParentCategory.Name</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What would your query look like to retrieve the data?

Comment: Just another question.  The HasOptional method says that the category might have an assiociated parent category.  Can't the same be said of the child categories?

Comment: @Brendan it is implied. A category may or may not have child categories.

Comment: The child categories list always seems to be instantiated, even if the count is 0.  Why is this?  But for parent category, if there is none then it null.  Why is this the case, why isn't the child category list not null if the count is 0?

Comment: @Brendan that is by design :) `null`s should be avoided if possible. [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)