# Tree stucture table and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have tree structure table like,

```
Table{Id, ParentId, Name}
```

where Id is primary key, and parent Id is a foreign key, but to the same table. It will have values like

```
Id            ParentId             Name
1              -                          N1

2              1                          N2

3              1                          N3

4              2                          N4
```

here, N2 and N3 is child of N1, and N4 a child of N2

I am using Entity framework and MVC to build rest like webservice.

How can I use entity framework to recursively to get all child nodes?

Comment: are you using code fist approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1 Retrieving self referencing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690849/entity-framework-4-1-retrieving-self-referencing-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I use entity framework to recursively to get all child nodes?

EF doesn't have support for recursive queries. You can map such structure easily as referenced by @Eranga in comment but once you load entities you must either manually define eager loading (= you must say how deep it should go) or your child entities will be loaded by lazy loading first time they are accessed (that is extremely inefficient).

The best way to work with hierarchical structures in EF is either using database view to hide hierarchical SQL query or using SQL / stored procedures directly.

Comment: It use to have this earlier. now with 4.3.1 its seems to be gone missing. Is there any ways to get that back ?

Comment: e.g Saying .Include("ChildCategories") would return all child and grand childs and super grand childs and so on. But Now it would just return the first level. I know I have tested and worked with categories a lot with EF.

Comment: @e10: EF never had this feature. Include loads only single level in hierarchy.